# Choosing language for web applications development

Tags: php

Hi If I want to choose a language for web development what all the factors I should take care?
And following things are important in my application , so keeping these in mind what language I should choose ?

1. Every user will be having an account ( need database programming)
2. Different Data should be shown at client side based on type of the user ( there will be different type of the users, some data will be common to all, some data will be specific)
3. Need to manage all the data efficiently at server side ( server side programming )
4. Give rich UI at client side .

Keeping all such things in mind, what language I should choose for web development? please mention in terms of client side and server side programming.

And I did go through the same kind of question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731685/learning-web-development-choosing-a-language-and-framework) , still am not clear with my doubt, expecting detailed answer. please Provide me necessary links, and I am thinking about php, ruby, JSP, but am not getting which one to choose and when?
Definitely It should be dependent on what I want, so above points tell that what exactly the application needs. Need to manage accounts, different data etc.

Comment: PHP, Ruby, Java (via JSP) all can. It just depends on what you can accommodate/afford on a server.

Comment: You can go with ruby language with rails framework.Also lots of service providers is offering hosting for rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Almost (if not all) every modern languages have database bindings, and even if not, database programming could still be done using other backends.
2. This is application specific, has nothing to do with programming language.
3. Language contributes very little to speed of execution. Compiler/interpreter implementation, algorithms, data structures, architectures, frameworks matter at a MUCH greater point.
4. The only (dynamic) web programming language that browsers understand is JavaScript. You can use any JavaScript framework or even any framework that could generate JavaScript code to manipulate user interface.

Answer (score 0):

For a general language:

- Will it run on the server I'm looking at getting, or the hosting service I plan to buy?
- Do I know it/can I learn it quickly?
- Does it have the features I need now, as well as in the future if I plan to expand my web app?

Your questions:

1. Does this language have a ready-build database interface? If so, good!
2. *Every* single language out there supports some sort of conditional (`if()`) statement. You just need to use them properly, with the data you have.
3. Back to the first bullet point; will my chosen language run on a webserver?
4. With a few exceptions (NodeJS, for example), you can't use the same language client and serverside. You'll need to know at least HTML and CSS for your "rich UI", or you could always hire a designer and leave yourself to do the backend.

Personally, I would recommend you use PHP for this project. It does everything you want, is *very* widely supported by web hosts, and is free to use. Most web IDEs work well with PHP, as do text editors.

Comment: A LAMP stack does seem likely with this question. Java less so, Ruby for the hipsters. What about Python? It would work well too.

Comment: And I would say [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/) for the "rich user interface". Not really server-language dependent for the most part.

Comment: @Jared Python, as well as Java and Ruby, would work too but the problem with those languages is that they're not as widely used on web hosting services as PHP. One could always use ASP.net, but I'd rather cut my own face off than recommend that. I'd say to just use CSS and normal HTML for a rich UI, then add any plugins you might want to use for, say, image carousels or something. Of course, jQuery is almost a must.

Comment: I usually equate `Java` and `.NET` together as "enterprise-grade", ie, "must support monolithic implementations". Both have their own utility, but for a run of the mill web server configuration, typically PHP and MySQL will give the most mileage.

Comment: @Jared Agreed, although PHP is easily able to do the same. It all comes down to personal preference (in this case), or whatever language your cheapest/chosen provider supports.

Comment: Believe it or not, Java and .NET do have upsides (that outfactor the downsides). For teams that factor in more than a few active developers, Java and .NET constructs can be very beneficial in the long run. PHP is not always the best option.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty you are describing just about any of the major server side scripting languages. It all comes down to how much experience you have with the language and which one has the API's / resources you need.

For example with PHP you can use Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla to power the CMS aspect of it all.

On the other hand if you had to script it all from hand then you just need to choose the language you prefer to use. Look at how the scripting language interacts with the database. Does it require much more code to access a query, are you comfortable using the language, can you use that language on your server?

PHP tends to be the no-brainer since it is widely support, there are plenty of resources and information all around the web due to it's popularity, and most of the major CMS's are written for it (meaning you don't have to write one yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider newer Web languages like [Opa](http://opalang.org/) or frameworks like [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) (with Ocaml), and you could also write your Web application; e.g. with [FastCgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) technology, in whatever language you are familiar with.